# How to encrypt and decrypt a simple string using AES128 or AES256 algorithms on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, ios6, aes

How do you *encrypt* and *decrypt* a string on iOS (AES256 or AES128)? I have looked through so many solution but couldn't find anything that works properly.

Example:

```
NSString *plainString = @"This string will be encrypted";
NSString *key = @"myKey";
```

Now, how do I encrypt **plainString** using **key**? And how do I do the opposite?

It can be either AES256 or AES128 algorithms, doesn't matter.

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Be very careful of the iOS Algorithms you find on the web for this.. many were written poorly and will fail to decode in other languages and generally not play nice due to padding and character encoding issues.

Comment: How are you expecting AES128 or 256 to work with an 80-bit key?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I come from openssl background, where encrypting and decrypting is as simple as using aes-256-cbc command. How does iOS go about encryption?

Comment: @KenrikMarch- Where I can get correct implementation of AES-128? It will be lot better if you can help?